# Declaring links using jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, seo

I use the following way to display the appropriate UI language in my web site. For example I declare links like this:

```
<nav>
    <a class="domain-about"></a>
    <a class="domain-downloads"></a>
</nav>
```

i.e. without any content inside the `<a>` tag, and without an `href=""` attribute, then I associate it with the following jQuery code:

```
$('.domain-about:lang(en)').attr('title','About').attr('href','about.php');
$('.domain-documentation:lang(en)').attr('title','Documentation').attr('href','documentation.php');
$('.domain-about:lang(ar)').attr('title','لمحة').attr('href','about-ar.php');
$('.domain-documentation:lang(ar)').attr('title','تعليمات').attr('href','documentation-ar.php');
```

Considering SEO, is this a good idea?

Comment: I see no problems with doing that. If you're worried about SEO consider generating a sitemap: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en

Comment: Not only does it defies normal linking convention but also it defies good practices for multi-language sites. Would reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a good idea for SEO because:

- There is no link that a search engine could follow
- There is no link text that would tell a search engine what the target url is about.

Some other approaches:

- Detect the right language on the server side and render matching html right away
- Render links in one language, THEN change it by JS
- Render all languages/links and hide those that are not active

I'd go for the last option as it gives a search engine a full sitemap to all pages in all languages.